# Can I connect 15A plug to 35A wiring.?

Tags: electrical

I got oven that had 15A but I got 10A socket nearby. A bit further I got switch with 35A. I am wondering I can draw extension from that 35A switch to my 15A Oven [image: Image of 35A switch I got]

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: Is that possible..??

Comment: What does the 35A switch feed? Where are you, perhaps Australia?

Comment: As of now its feeds nothing mate. Yes mate I am Australia

Comment: Don’t your devices have fuses in the plugs? I remember the coffee maker having fuses in the plug when I visited. If the oven has fuses I would think it could be used, on this side of the pond it could not be done as we don’t fuse our plugs and are limited to 150% of the listing for the breaker size.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The oven draws 15A of current and the switch is able to carry up to 35A of current. You need to check the wiring upstream of the switch and make sure every circuit is able to carry at least 15A.

Comment: Or, check the breaker that feeds it.

Answer (score 0):

No , you need to check the c/b rating and cable size of the circuit you are messing with.That 35A switch is just an isolater, meaning it can isolate 35A safely and is not a true indication of current capacity of the circuit.